# In Monster anime, what made Johan so special?

Tags: monster

Why was everyone who knew Johan, so convinced that he was a superior figure or someone special, especially from the time that he was a kid?

The show gave a lot of instances where everyone who knew Johan, was rather impressed by him and regarded him as a kind of leader never seen before. In fact, many, like Baby, wanted him to become the next Hitler.

But what was so special about him? 
 Did the show really give any reasoning behind this?

Comment: You might want to split those questions up into different questions.

Comment: *Please* split up your questions. There's simply too much to over in order to answer those 3 questions.